# How to make email templates for mailgun?

Tags: heroku, parse-server, mailgun, email-templates

I just got `mailgun` set up with `parse-server` on `heroku`.

Here is the kind of mail a user gets for mail verification when a new account is created:

> Hi,
>
> You are being asked to confirm the e-mail address blablah@example.com
>   with TheGreatApp
>
> Click here to confirm it:
>   https://thegreatapp.herokuapp.com/parse/apps/XXXXX/verify_email?token=YYYYYY&username=xyz

That does the job, but it would nice to be able to customize the message a little bit.

*I already tried following some post I found on SOF, but with no success.*

So what is the proper way to do that? And is it possible to have the message in several languages?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide custom templates in the mailgun-adapter configuration, as described in the [docs](https://github.com/sebsylvester/parse-server-mailgun).

Currently there is no built-in way to support multiple languages. And since Mustache is used as templating engine, it's also not possible to have any custom i18n logic inside the templates. However, recently there was a discussion in the *parseopensource* Slack channel where some users were talking about plans to contribute such a feature.